# Загрузка нескольких файлов через форму в Django

Tags: django, файлы

Создаю проект, в котором есть форма для добавления документа, в том числе загрузка файлов в этой же форме. Всё вроде работает. Но столкнулся с проблемой, никак не могу сделать, чтобы можно было загружать несколько файлов.
**Models.py**

```
class Document(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Заголовок", max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField("Ссылка", max_length=250, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             verbose_name="Пользователь",
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, verbose_name="Категория", related_name="categories",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name="Текст", blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(verbose_name="Вложения", blank=True,
                            null=True, upload_to=file_directory_path)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Дата создания")
    date_update = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True, verbose_name="Дата обновления")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Документ"
        verbose_name_plural = "Документы"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("document_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class DocumentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        file = forms.FileField(
            widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
        fields = ['title', 'category', 'text', 'file']
```

**Views.py**

```
class DocumentCreate(CreateView):
    model = DocumentForm
    form_class = DocumentForm
    extra_context = {'documents': Document.objects.all()}
    template_name = 'base/createdocument.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdocument = form.save(commit=False)
            newdocument.user = request.user
            newdocument.slug = translit(newdocument.title,
                                        language_code='ru',
                                        reversed=True)
            newdocument.slug = slugify(newdocument.slug)
            newdocument.save()
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

**createdocument.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}   {% block content %}
    <h1> Создание документа</h1>
    <h2>{{error}}</h2>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" >
        {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ form.as_p }}</p>
        <button type="submit">Создать</button> 
    </form> {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525188/upload-multiple-files-in-django

Comment: Увы, но нет, я уже пользовался этой статьей. Выбор в проводнике нескольких файлов я исправил, но вот в админке отображается всего 1.